# How to retrieve the data from one object in another object?

Tags: c#, .net

I create 3 classes then those 3 classes's object create in another class. Now I want to read the data from the database.
My code is: I am retrieving the data from the database and call from the combo box.

```
       SqlConnection conn = MyDB.GetConnection();
       string selectStm = "SELECT c.CourseID,en.Score,s.StudentID FROM EnrollmentTable en,Course c,Student s WHERE en.StudentID = s.StudentID AND en.CourseID = c.CourseID";

       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectStm, conn);
       //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", StudentID);


       List<StudentScore> aStudentScore = new List<StudentScore>();

       StudentScore score = null;



       try
       {
           conn.Open();
           SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


           Enrollment enr = new Enrollment();

           while (reader.Read())
           {
               score = new StudentScore();



               score.EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID = reader["StudentID"].ToString();//Here is the problem.
               score.EnrollmentData.CourseData.CourseID = reader["CourseID"].ToString();//Here is the problem.

               score.Score = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Score"]);



               aStudentScore.Add(score);
           }

           reader.Close();
           return aStudentScore;
       }
       catch (SqlException ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
       finally
       {
           conn.Close();
       }
```

It doesn't take any value....How can I do it?

Comment: i mean, i want to retrieve the data from table what it doesn't retrieve the data...

Comment: What? What shows null? Can you post the exception traceback?

Comment: Even it doesn't show any exception.:(

Comment: debug it to see if you have the value in the reader

Comment: it shows EnrollmentData is null.

Comment: Was the `EnrollmentData` class inside of `score` instantiated?  Same for `StudentData` and `CourseData` inside of `EnrollmentData`?

Comment: it tried:    Student st = new Student();
               Course cr = new Course();
             Enrollment enr = new Enrollment();
               while (reader.Read()){ StudentScore score = new StudentScore();

                   score.EnrollmentData = enr;

                   enr.CourseData = cr;
                   enr.StudentData = st
                   st.StudentID = reader["StudentID"].ToString();
                   cr.CourseID = reader["CourseID"].ToString();
                   score.Score = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Score"]);                   aStudentScore.Add(score);
               }

Comment: No score is in StudentScore class and in StudentScore i create score variable and Enrollment EnrollmentData  ;     In enrollment i create Student StudentData and Course CourseData.

Comment: Before this line  "while (reader.Read())" add a line "Debug.WriteLine(read.HasRows.ToString())"  My bet is your query returned zero rows.  Did you try a copy paste of selectStm to SSMS?

Comment: yeah it return zero rows:(.No i didn't copy i thought in C# we can write same way..

Comment: If the query returned zero rows then reader.Read() will find zero rows.  Copy paste into SSMS to fix the query so it returns more than zero rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `SELECT` statement is not returning any rows, then there is a problem with your data.  Either the `EnrollmentTable.StudentID` doesn't match any records in the `Student` table or `EnrollmentTable.CourseID` doesn't match any courses in the `Course` table.

In any case, I tried to simplify the code so it would be easier to read:

```
public class Student
{
    string studentID = string.Empty;
    public string StudentID
    {get { return studentID;}
     set { studentID = value;}}
};

public class Course
{
    string courseID = string.Empty;
    public string CourseID
    {get { return courseID;}
     set { courseID = value;}}
};

public class Enrollment
{
    Student studentData = new Student();
    public Student StudentData
    {get { return studentData;}
     set { studentData = value;}
    }
    Course courseData = new Course();
    public Course CourseData
    {get { return courseData; }
     set { courseData = value; }}
};

public class StudentScore
{
    Enrollment enrollmentData = new Enrollment();
    public Enrollment EnrollmentData
    {get { return enrollmentData;}
     set { enrollmentData = value;}}

    int score = 0;
    public int Score
    {get {return score;}
     set {score = value;}}
};

public List<StudentScore> getScoreList()
{
    List<StudentScore> aStudentScore = new List<StudentScore>();
    StringBuilder tmpSQL = new StringBuilder();
    tmpSQL.Append("SELECT c.CourseID, en.Score, s.StudentID ");
    tmpSQL.Append("FROM EnrollmentTable en ");
    tmpSQL.Append("       INNER JOIN Student s ON en.StudentID = s.StudentID ");
    tmpSQL.Append("       INNER JOIN Course c ON en.CourseID = c.CourseID ");
    try
    {using (SqlConnection conn = MyDB.GetConnection()){
       conn.Open();
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(tmpSQL.ToString(), conn)){
         using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()){
           while (reader.Read())
             {
              StudentScore score = new StudentScore();
              score.EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID = reader["StudentID"].ToString();
              score.EnrollmentData.CourseData.CourseID = reader["CourseID"].ToString();
              score.Score = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Score"]);
              aStudentScore.Add(score);
              };
            };
         };
      };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {throw ex;}
    return aStudentScore; 
}
```

Comment: @user1050667, if you are getting 0 rows returned, then there is a problem with the data or your data structure.  The `SELECT` statement is a pretty straight forward double inner join.  It should be returning every enrollment record in your table.  If it isn't, then you need to look at the data in the EnrollmentTable, Student table and Course table and see if they manually match.  (Maybe one is a VarChar and other is integer or float?)

Comment: every thing is matched but it still showed null value i think which one we give path like :  **score.EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID = reader["StudentID"].ToString();** I think this one have a problem.it shows null..

Comment: @user1050667, As one of the earlier commentators suggested, have you run the query in SQL Server Management Studio to see what the results are?  If so, post some of the results.